# ¿Cómo accedo a los cambios de la rama oculta "origin/master"?

Tags: git, github

Cuando realizado:

```
git fetch origin
```

Obtengo una rama oculta "origin/master" previa.

¿Existe algún procedimiento por el cual pueda acceder a esa rama antes de hacer?

```
git merge origin/master
```

Me gustaría ver si los cambios afectarían a mi repositorio local.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo normal es que trabajes en una rama a parte. Yo haría lo siguiente suponiendo que estás trabajando en master:

```
git checkout -b feature/nueva_feature
```

Con esto creas una rama con tu código

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

Con esto te descargas master

```
git checkout feature/nueva_feature
git diff master
```

Con esto obtienes las diferencias entre tu rama y master

```
git merge master
git push -u origin feature/nueva_feature
```

Con esto haces un merge de master en tu rama y la subes al repositorio remoto.
Si utilizas github o bitbucket puedes crear una pull request desde la web y hacer el merge, si no desde la línea de comandos:

```
git checkout master
git merge feature/nueva_feature
git push
```

Con esto lo subes a master.

Comment: cuando ejecuto el comando

Comment: cuando ejecuto el comando `git pull` no ocurre nada. ¿Puedes aclararme este punto, por favor?

Comment: puedes hacerlo en cualquier momento antes de hacer el pull de master. Mientras no hagas el pull de master tu rama no se habrá tocado y podras crear la nueva rama con checkout -b. La respuesta exacta a tu pregunta es la de @idelcano, pero yo prefiero trabajar rama por feature aunque al principio parezca más complicado.

Comment: si al hacer ```git pull``` no estas recibiendo nada, es que tienes exactamente la misma versión que hay en el repositorio remoto

Answer (score 0):

si solo quieres ver las diferencias puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
git diff ramalocal origin/master
```

Aunque como comenta TlmaK0 deberías crear una nueva rama por cada nueva característica que desarrolles, y luego una vez acabada mezclarias esa rama contra master.